# unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest on install stable/rabbitmq-ha

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

When trying to install "rabbitmq-ha" I have an error:

```
$ helm install rabbitmq stable/rabbitmq-ha
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "PrometheusRule" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1"
```

Version of Helm and Kubernetes:

- Version of Helm : "v3.2.1"
- Version of Kubernetes : "v1.17.5-0"

Comment: Before installing rabbitmq-ha please check if you got the Prometheus Operator installed. Try setting `prometheus.operator.enabled` to `false`.

Comment: @OhHiMark thanks, is created! but pod status keep "Pending"
rmq-rabbitmq-ha-0                  0/1     Pending

Comment: Could you provide the logs from that pod?

Comment: @OhHiMark when execute 
$ kubectl logs rmq-rabbitmq-ha-0

the result is nothing
Is there another way?

Comment: Execute `kubectl describe pods ${POD_NAME}` and post the output in the question by editing it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using this command to install RabbitMQ:

```
helm install --set replicaCount=2 \
               --set rabbitmqUsername=yourUSERNAME \
               --set rabbitmqPassword=yourPASSWORD \
               --set prometheus.operator.enabled=false \
               ha-rabbitmq stable/rabbitmq-ha
```

but I opened the [issue](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/22346) on Github for helm-chart and a contributor on the project  [say](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/22346#issuecomment-628280070):

> Confirming the bug too. This is caused by the following PR: #21274
> (comment)
>
> The regression was released in rabbitmq-ha chart version 1.44.2.
> 1.44.1 works OK.

Comment: @OhHiMark see that

Answer (score 0):

I am using this flag for the RabbitMQ helm deployment. It worked for me.

```
--set prometheus.operator.enabled=false
```